# (Drupal) How to only target elements within node with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, toggle

I'm a beginner with jQuery and I have this HTML:

```
<a class="a2a_dd" href="https://www.addtoany.com/share_save"><img src="//static.addtoany.com/buttons/favicon.png" width="0" height="0" border="0" alt="Share"/>Share</a>

<div id="share-btns">
 <div id="facebook">
  <a class="a2a_button_facebook"></a>
 </div>

 <div id="google_plus">
  <a class="a2a_button_google_plus"></a>
 </div>

 <a class="a2a_button_twitter">
  <div id="twitter"></div>
 </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to use jQuery to make it so when you click on the .a2a_dd link, it will toggle the #share-btns div visibility. Here is my code:

```
(function($){
Drupal.behaviors.toggle = {
  attach: function() {
    $('.a2a_dd').click(function() {
      $('#share-btns').fadeToggle();
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

The problem is, I have a grid of teaser articles all on the same page that all have this HTML on them and when I click on the .a2a_dd link on any of the teasers it toggles the #share-btns div on only the first teaser on the page. Is there a way to get jQuery to recognize the node that was clicked on so it can toggle the div from that same node? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is there another wrapping element for each group of buttons and link? That would help isolate the instances

Comment: I'm sorry yes there is, it's a span element with class .a2a_kit

Comment: OK. Then use the pattern `$(this).closest('.a2a_ki').find('[id=share-btns]')`. It looks up to that parent wrapper and then isolates within it. ID's are not supposed to repeat in a page thus the `[id=..]` selector

Comment: Thank you this also works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix using [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/). You need to target the element right after the toggle link (according to your html structure).

```
$('.a2a_dd').click(function() {
  $(this).next().fadeToggle();
});
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qq5pVrtEJqIEZO2E3fwX) example.